# scrollToItemAtIndexPath after changing cell size

Tags: ios, scroll, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView that contains simple sections and rows, i.e. cells. Cells are resized with a pinch gesture recognizer.

After the cells have resized i want want the old first visible cell to stay on top to give the user some control about the position he's zooming in or out to. I store the index path of that cell and call scrollToItemAtIndexPath, but the results are rather random. Sometimes it keeps the old first visible cell in the top visible row, but mostly fails and that cell is somewhere off screen when making the cells larger and somewhere in the middle when making cells smaller.

I suspect the layout of the subviews cycle or something related is not correct for the scrolling to get called appropriately ?

```
-(IBAction)pinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)pinchRecognizer
{
    CVflowlayout *scaleLayout = (CVflowlayout *)[self.MainCollection collectionViewLayout];

    if (pinchRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        pinchRecognizer.scale = [scaleLayout itemSize] / 50;
    }

    else if (pinchRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged || pinchRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        cvCellScale = pinchRecognizer.scale;
        NSInteger newCellSize = (int)(50 * cvCellScale);

        // get sorted index paths and first visible cell path
        NSArray *sortedIndexPaths = [MainCollection.indexPathsForVisibleItems sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
            NSIndexPath *path1 = (NSIndexPath *)obj1;
            NSIndexPath *path2 = (NSIndexPath *)obj2;
            return [path1 compare:path2];
        }];
        NSIndexPath *sortedFirst = [sortedIndexPaths objectAtIndex:0];
        visibleFirst = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sortedFirst.row inSection:sortedFirst.section];

        scaleLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(newCellSize, newCellSize);

        /// ---- What is wrong here ? -------
        [MainCollection setNeedsLayout];
        [MainCollection layoutIfNeeded];
        [MainCollection scrollToItemAtIndexPath:visibleFirst atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];

    }

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't exactly explain why that isn't working, but I would instead try to use

```
[MainCollection setContentOffset:...];
```

and figure out the content offset yourself. It will be your cell height times the number of cells above your top visible cell plus any cell spacing you have in place.

Comment: Edit: You might be on to something. It is probably even simpler, [MainCollection layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath].frame.origin.y; gives the y coordinate and it is correctly updated at this stage